# Maintain same button size regardless of content

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons that have different width values because the content is different. My desire result is to have the same width on both buttons.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eczfs61x/1/)

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="options ion-text-center">
    <div class="option-container" (click)="newScenario()" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <div class="option">
        <img src="assets/icons/scenario.svg" class="option-icon">
        <label class="option-text">Create scenario</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="option-container" (click)="goToHistory()" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <div class="option">
        <img src="assets/icons/scenario.svg" class="option-icon">
        <label class="option-text">History</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .options {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 15em;
  margin-top: 6em;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  justify-items: center;
  float: right;

  .option-container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 12px;
    justify-content: right;


    .option {
      background-color: #49515C;
      // width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 1rem 2rem;
      border-radius: 12px;
      filter: drop-shadow(0px 8px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));

    


      .option-icon {
        filter: invert(100%) sepia(4%) saturate(7500%) hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(109%) contrast(122%);
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
      }

      .option-text {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding-left: 10px;
        font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
      }
    }
  }

  .option-container:nth-child(2) {
    justify-content: left;
  }
}
```

The first thing I try is to set option class to `width: 100%;` but both buttons get bigger and I want to keep the current "Create Scenario" button.

My second try was to adjust "History button" as `&__justify-content {width: 41%;}` but this does not work on responsive layout.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what if you give specific width in px like (200px)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this two css properties:

```css
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work